# How can I make an icon / shortcut / link for ampps

Tags: desktop

I usually start ampps using a terminal:

1. `cd /usr/local/ampps`
2. `sudo ./Ampps`
3. *enter password*

How can I make a shortcut / link in my destkop to avoid the typing?
Using ubuntu 14 (if that makes a difference).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First make sure you have gnome-tweak-tool installed:

```
sudo apt-get install gnome-tweak-tool
```

Then use this command from a terminal:

```
gnome-desktop-item-edit --create-new ~/Desktop
```